# Missing faces in Quake 3 BSP

Tags: binary-space-partitioning, quake3

I'm attempting to write a level viewer for Quake 3 levels (repo [here](https://github.com/jFransham/quake-level-loader)). I've got some of the way towards it, but for every level I try to view with it I get lots of missing faces.

[image: Missing faces in quake level]
*(image from Dustbowl)*

In the above image, I have disabled backface culling in order to show where faces are missing a little better.

My question is, has anyone else run into this problem? I know Quake/Quake 3 level rendering is a well-trodden path, so I'm luckier than most in this situation. I so far only render meshes and polygons, not models, but most of the missing faces seem to be where one would expect static faces.

I'm not really asking for a code review, as much of the implementation details I would not expect to be common (I transform the BSP tree into a proper tree structure and discard the index-based structure entirely), but if anyone has seen this before I'd love to know what the issue was.

Comment: You might need to reverse the windings according to the side of the face its normal falls on.

Comment: See: "disabled backface culling". I believe this is precalculated correctly though, I get sensible results if I turn it on.

Comment: This might be because Quake 3 uses patches (curved bezier faces) _way_ more extensively than I expected. Guess it's time to bite the bullet and implement bezier curves.